# SceneKit: How to add buttons (or other controls) on a SCNView

Tags: macos, scenekit

I'm presenting a 3D model using the SceneKit, and I want to add some buttons on top of the SCNView to let users to control the model (e.g. change the color). I add the view and button in Storyboard. However, when I run the app, the button is not shown at all. So how to achieve the feature with lease effort?

The screenshot is in the following links. (Forget about the crazy display in the app, I just build a toy app to show that the button is not shown and not adding any scene to the SCNView)

[Design in Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7iuJ.png)
[image: Design in Storyboard]
[Running result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScRQD.png)

[image: Running result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to make your views layer-backed. This can be done in the View Effects inspector in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works and I'll learn more about the layer-backed view from the documentation.